# Which HTTP request to execute a command on server?

Tags: rest, express, http, httprequest

I am learning how to build a website with node.js +express. When I click on a button (in the browser), it prints "hello" in the node.js console. It worked (this is not the problem). To do that, I created a app.**get** route. 
But I wonder which http request methods (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4), I should use to conform to the REST architectural style.

- **GET** must be used to read
- **POST** must be used to create
- **PUT** must be used to update and to create
- **DELETE** must be used to delete
- ...

I do not read, create, update, delete, ... anything. I just run a command on the server (Of course, print hello is not the final goal. I plan to run more complex commands).

Thanks for answer.

Comment: It will depend on what "command" you want to run. REST is all about "resources". See https://medium.com/qudini-engineering/rest-over-http-or-why-your-http-api-isnt-restful-94fd92a0e6d4 for a quick overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) there is no "REST standard" - it's an architectural style; HTTP *can* be used to implement "RESTful" services

b) PUT is for creation as well

c) How your server does things (such as by "executing" something) doesn't really matter. Think in terms of URIs, the resources they identify, and what you can do with them.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I edit my question following your a and b points. If I understand the c point : I must use GET if I change nothing in the resources. Right ?

Comment: If the server does not change state, GET should be always correct.